# Behavior testing with Moq: how to set expectations on a non-virtual property

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm new to Moq and I wonder how I could write the following test if the "Bounds" property is not declared virtual.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SettingSize_Sets_Bounds_ExactlyOnce()
{
    // given
    var mock = new Mock<Visual>();
    var anonymSize = DrawingHelper.AnonymousSize();
    // when 
    mock.Object.Size = anonymSize;
    // then
    mock.VerifySet(visual => visual.Bounds = new Rectangle(DrawingHelper.Origin(),anonymSize), Times.Once());
}
```

To provide a little context, the Visual class implements the IVIsual interface, where the Bounds property is declared. Therefore, I could use the interface to create the Mock object, but I don't see how I should change the above test to still test the behavior of the concrete IVisual implementer (Visual class).

Specifically, I want to ensure that when property Size is set, then the non-virtual property Bounds is also set.

Is this possible with Moq? If not what are the frameworks out there that would allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `when` is not correct.

```
mock.Object.Size = anonymSize;
```

**You are testing the mock**: you are assigning a value to a property of a mock object while you need to test a real object. Provide more info on the actual object which you are trying to test.

---

### UPDATE

You do not need a mock, **you test the class while mocking the dependencies.** You do not seem to have any dependency here.

So what I would do is:

```
// Given
Visual v = new Visual();

// When
v.Size = someSize;

// Then
Assert.That(v.Bounds == someExpectedBounds);
```

Comment: @Aliostad: I see, and as a matter of fact you are right. What I'd like to test is that the concrete implementation of the Visual class does call property Bounds when Size is updated. My idea was to make this contract explicit by creating a test that checked this expected behavior. Hope this makes my intention clearer, let me know if it doesn't. And thanks again for your answer, really appreciated your feedback!

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that Visual is an abstract class with a protected constructor.

Comment: I suppose my last comment did come too late, sorry about that. Visual is abstract and the constructor is protected, so I cannot do this (and I don't want to change the API class as it makes sense to keep it abstract and not directly instantiable). Further, I would like to use behavior verification, and not state verification (but if using behavior verification in this situation is wrong I would definitely like if someone could elaborate why it is so).

Comment: Write a class in your test which just inherits from it and then test it.

Comment: Yes, this works for state verification. And I end up figuring what I should do to use behavior testing (simply, I have a design problem and I need to improve it if I want to go with behavior testing). Thanks a lot for your inputs! I've find them useful and they made me avoid to write useless tests by mocking the SUT:)